# Mouse freeze after logging in to Gnome

Tags: arch-linux, gnome3, mouse

I did my first Arch Linux install yesterday. I later installed Gnome and I'm able to log in.

The touchpad and mouse buttons work at the log in screen but once I'm logged on the Touchpad does not work.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution to this problem for me:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=196427

In there, it gives instuction to put `needs_root_rights=yes` in the `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config`. e.g.:

```
echo "needs_root_rights=yes" > /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config
```

This is after installing the package `xf86-input-evdev`.

Answer (score -1):

Had similar issue on Debian after dist-upgrade.

This fixed the cursor movement:

```
dpkg-reconfigure x11-common
```